# Change digest for Devise::TokenGenerator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I want to use md5 instead of sha256 for Devise::TokenGenerator . What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own encryptor.

```
# lib/devise/encryptors/md5.rb
require 'digest/md5'

module Devise
  module Encryptors
    class Md5 < Base
      def self.digest(password, stretches, salt, pepper)
        str = [password, salt].flatten.compact.join
        Digest::MD5.hexdigest(str)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can then set this as your encryptor in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.encryptor = :md5
```

Don’t forget to enable the :encryptable in your User model.

Also, you should make sure that the new file is loaded, for instance by adding this to your users' class:

```
require Rails.root.join('lib', 'devise', 'encryptors', 'md5')
```